# Piping an arraylist from first script to second script

Tags: powershell

I need to pipe an arraylist from script n.1 to script n.2 and modify it with a while cycle

## script n.1 - PS-GetBak.ps1

```bsh
[System.Collections.Arraylist]$ArrBkp=@()

$ArrObj = New-Object psobject -Property @{Type="Full";Id=1001}
[void]$ArrBkp.Add($ArrObj)

$ArrObj = New-Object psobject -Property @{Type="Diff";Id=1002}
[void]$ArrBkp.Add($ArrObj)

$ArrObj = New-Object psobject -Property @{Type="Full";Id=1003}
[void]$ArrBkp.Add($ArrObj)

$ArrObj = New-Object psobject -Property @{Type="Diff";Id=1004}
[void]$ArrBkp.Add($ArrObj)

$ArrObj = New-Object psobject -Property @{Type="Diff";Id=1005}
[void]$ArrBkp.Add($ArrObj)

$ArrBkp
```

## script n.2 - PS-Rest.ps1

```bsh
[CmdletBinding()]Param(
[Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
$ArrBkp,
[Parameter()]
$Id
)

$ArrBkp.Reverse()

foreach ($Bkp in $ArrBkp) {
    while ($Bkp.Id -gt $Id) {$Bkp;$ArrBkp.Remove($Bkp)}
}

$ArrBkp
```

What I expect is:

```
PS C:\Users\dio\Documents\script\PS-Rest> .\PS-GetBak.ps1 | .\PS-Rest.ps1 -Id 1004
   Id Type
   -- ----
 1004 Diff
 1003 Full
 1002 Diff
 1001 Full
```

Explained: while loop should remove object from arraylist that has Id value gt 1004

Actual result:
Only the last value from arraylist is piped to the script n.2 causing while loop error

```
In C:\Users\dio\Documents\script\PS-Rest\PS-Rest.ps1:11 car:49
+     while ($Bkp.Id -gt $Id) {$Bkp;$ArrBkp.Remove <<<< ($Bkp)}
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Remove:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

Comment: since things are running independently there is NO pipeline to connect the two. [*grin*] instead, you will need to provide an intermediate data holder - a file. JSON is the usual one, but the `*-CliXml` cmdlets are PoSh-aware and may be easier to use.

Comment: Usually an array sent over the pipe gets processed one element at at time by the next command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I reworked it, so it's pretty close to the original.  Except I'm passing on the pipe by property name.  I'm sort of smuggling the arraylist under a sub-property.  For some reason, a PS script can't return an arraylist at the top level.  And a pipeline would only process an element at a time anyway.  And collecting the elements to delete, and then deleting in a second loop.  This way it doesn't break the first loop. Also, having a while statement doesn't make sense, since the condition would never change after a remove.

ps-getbk.ps1:

```
[System.Collections.Arraylist]$ArrBkp=@()

$ArrObj = New-Object psobject -Property @{Type="Full";Id=1001}
[void]$ArrBkp.Add($ArrObj)

$ArrObj = New-Object psobject -Property @{Type="Diff";Id=1002}
[void]$ArrBkp.Add($ArrObj)

$ArrObj = New-Object psobject -Property @{Type="Full";Id=1003}
[void]$ArrBkp.Add($ArrObj)

$ArrObj = New-Object psobject -Property @{Type="Diff";Id=1004}
[void]$ArrBkp.Add($ArrObj)

$ArrObj = New-Object psobject -Property @{Type="Diff";Id=1005}
[void]$ArrBkp.Add($ArrObj)

[pscustomobject]@{ArrBkp=$ArrBkp}
```

ps-rest.ps1:

```
[CmdletBinding()]Param(
  [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
  $ArrBkp,
  [Parameter()]$Id
)

$ArrBkp.Reverse()

$dellist = foreach ($Bkp in $ArrBkp) {
    if ($Bkp.Id -gt $Id) {$Bkp}
}

foreach ($Bkp in $dellist) {
    $ArrBkp.remove($Bkp)
}

$ArrBkp
```

Output from `.\PS-GetBak.ps1 | .\PS-Rest.ps1 -Id 1004`

```
  Id Type
  -- ----
1004 Diff
1003 Full
1002 Diff
1001 Full
```

Answer (score 2):

Taking a step back:

**PowerShell creates (`[object[]]`) arrays on demand, and "modifying" arrays often means simply *automatically* creating *copies* of the original arrays with modifications applied.**

Unless performance and conservation of memory are paramount, there is **often no reason to use types such as `[System.Collections.ArrayList]` in PowerShell**.

This includes the initial *construction* of arrays, given that:

- outputting *multiple* objects from a script sends them one by one through the pipeline and collects them *implicitly* in an array when assigned to a variable.
- PowerShell's `,` operator for explicitly construction arrays is very flexible.

Thus, your `PS-GetBak.ps1` script can be simplified as follows:

```
# Construct multiple custom objects and send them all to the pipeline.
[pscustomobject] @{Type="Full";Id=1001}
[pscustomobject] @{Type="Diff";Id=1002}
[pscustomobject] @{Type="Full";Id=1003}
[pscustomobject] @{Type="Diff";Id=1004}
[pscustomobject] @{Type="Diff";Id=1005}
```

Now you can let `PS-Rest.ps1` perform a *filtering* operation on the input and simply *omit* unwanted inputs while passing the others through:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
  [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
  $Bkp
  ,
  $Id
)

process {
  if ($Bkp.Id -le $Id) {
    $_ # pass through
  }
}
```

Note the use of a `process` block, which is required to process all pipeline inputs, one at a time.

However, this **doesn't address the desired *reversing* of the resulting array (list)**, but you could **do that after the fact**:

```
# Chain the two scripts in a pipeline and collect the result.
$resultArray = @(PS-GetBak.ps1 | PS-Rest.ps1 -Id 1004)
[array]::Reverse($resultArray) # reverse the array in place.
```

Note the `@(...)` around the pipeline, which ensures that the output is *always* an array, given that PowerShell would report a *single* output object as-is, not as a single-element array.

---

If you do want to **integrate reversing of the array into `PS-Rest.ps1`**, more work is needed, using a [`System.Collections.Stack`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.stack) instance:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
  [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
  $Bkp
  ,
  $Id
)

begin {
  # Create a stack as an aux. data structure for output in reverse order.
  $stack = [Collections.Stack]::new()
}

process {
  if ($Bkp.Id -le $Id) {
    $stack.Push($_) # add to stack
  }
}

end {
  # Output the stack, which enumerates the elements in reverse order.
  $stack
}
```

The call is then simplified to:

```
$reversedResultArray = @(PS-GetBak.ps1 | PS-Rest.ps1 -Id 1004)
```