# ArrayLists and Advanced Functions

Tags: powershell

I've got an ArrayList of ArrayLists of Strings that I need to process with an advanced function. I am modeling that function off of what I learned in "Learn Powershell Toolmaking in a Month of Lunches."

In order to make the functions flexible, they tell you in that book to set it up so that a parameter can be piped in, but also taken as an array. So basically, you make the advanced function to accept `ValuesFromPipeline` for a particular parameter, but then you also make that parameter type an array and add a `ForEach-Object` in your Process.

What I am running into is that if I configure my function this way, it no longer works to pipe the values in. Because then it treats them one at a time, and the `ForEach-Object` breaks that ArrayList into its subsequent strings for processing. Is there an easy way to prevent this?

See code example below. When I pass `$OutsideArray` to `Get-Data` as a normal parameter (`Get-Data $OutsideArray`), it works. When I remove the `ForEach-Object` in the function, it works. But when I pipe `$OutsideArray` in as is, it no longer works.

Have tried stepping through to see if I can understand why it acts this way, but so far no luck.

```bsh
function Get-Data {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $True, ValueFromPipeline = $True)]
        [System.Collections.ArrayList]$ModuleBlocks
    )

    PROCESS {
        $ModuleBlocks | % {
            $test = $_
        }
    }
}

$OutsideArray = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

For ($i = 0; $i -lt 10; $i++) {

    $InsideArray = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

    For ($j = 0; $j -le 10; $j++) {
        $InsideArray.Add("$i This is a test $j") | Out-Null
    }

    $OutsideArray.Add($InsideArray) | Out-Null
}

$OutsideArray | Get-Data
```

Comment: How about ValueFromPipelineByParameterName?

Comment: Can you please expand on that a bit? Never heard of it.

Comment: I recommend running `help about_Functions_Advanced_Parameters` and reading the built-in help.

Comment: How do you know whether it works or not? Your `Get-Data` function never returns or emits anything

Comment: Removed `$test = ` from your code. I'm getting the same output when running `$OutsideArray | Get-Date` and `Get-Data $OutsideArray`

Comment: I'm just stepping through it in an IDE to see how it's treating the data within the function.

Answer (score 0):

How about ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName?  You can pipe the arraylist in as a property of another object.  I posted a similar answer here (unscored):  [Piping an arraylist from first script to second script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57340040/piping-an-arraylist-from-first-script-to-second-script/57340735#57340735)

EDIT:  I thought of a second way.  Pass it in using the comma operator:

```
$a = [collections.arraylist](1,2,3)
,$a | foreach gettype

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     ArrayList                                System.Object
```